# Count number of occurrences of list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, list-comprehension

I need to write a function that takes 3 arguments: `data`, `year_start`, `year_end`.

The `data` is a list of tuples. `year_start` and `year_end` are inputs by the user.

The function needs to count the number of occurrences in `data`, where any year in the date range is in position [0] (position [0] in `data` is the year).

I need to generate lists of tuples for `earthquake_count_by_year = []`, and `total_damage_by_year = []` in the format `[(year, value), (year, value)]` for each year in the range.

Here's what I have:

```
def summary_statistics(data, year_start, year_end):
    earthquake_count_by_year = []
    total_damages_by_year = []
    casualties_by_year = []
    count = 0
    years = []
    year_start = int(year_start)
    year_end = int(year_end)
    
    if year_end >= year_start:
        # store range of years into list
        years = list(range(year_start, year_end+1))
        for index, tuple in enumerate(data):
            if tuple[0] in years:
                count[tuple[0]] += 1
        print(count)
```

The above is just my attempt to count the number of occurrences in the input for each year.
I feel like if I can get this much, I can figure out the rest.

Here is the input for `data`:

```
[(2020, 1, 6.0, 'CHINA:  XINJIANG PROVINCE', 39.831, 77.106, 1, 0, 2, 0), (2020, 1, 6.7, 'TURKEY:  ELAZIG AND MALATYA PROVINCES', 38.39, 39.081, 41, 0, 1600, 0), (2018, 1, 7.7, 'CUBA: GRANMA;  CAYMAN IS;  JAMAICA', 19.44, -78.755, 0, 0, 0, 0), (2019, 2, 6.0, 'TURKEY: VAN;  IRAN', 38.482, 44.367, 10, 0, 60, 0), (2018, 3, 5.4, 'BALKANS NW:  CROATIA:  ZAGREB', 45.897, 15.966, 1, 0, 27, 6000.0), (2020, 3, 5.7, 'USA: UTAH', 40.751, -112.078, 0, 0, 0, 48.5), (2020, 3, 7.5, 'RUSSIA:  KURIL ISLANDS', 48.986, 157.693, 0, 0, 0, 0)]
```

Expected output for list_of_earthquake_count_by_year(data, 2018, 2020):

```
[(2020, 3), (2019, 0), (2018, 2)]
```

Ultimately, the rest of what I need is:
casualties_by_year(data, 2018, 2020):

```
(year, (total_deaths, total_missing, total_injured))
```

Which ends up in:

```
L = [[earthquake_count_by_year], [casualties_by_year]]
return L
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: index[0] (year), the count of how many times that year shows up, and index[9], index[8], index[7] is deaths, missing, injured. I realize a list comprehension would be useful here, but that is above my skill level right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `count = 0` initializes `count` as an integer but in the line `count[tuple[0]] += 1`, you seem to be treating it as a dictionary which is the source of the problem. You should initialize the variable `count` as a dictionary like so:

```
count = {}
```

Now since dictionary is being used, minor changes have to be done to the code:

```
if tuple[0] in years:
    # If the key does not exist in the dictionary, create one
    if tuple[0] not in count:
        count[tuple[0]] = 0

    count[tuple[0]] += 1
```

All the data will be stored within the `count` dictionary as:

```
{
    2020: 3,
    2018: 2,
    2019: 0
}
```

Now, all you need to do is convert the data from dictionary to list of tuples, which couldn't be easier than this:

```
list_of_tuples = list(count.items())    # Returns list of tuples
return list_of_tuples
```

Comment: Well thanks for the detailed response. But that gives me an "'int' object is not subscriptable" error. There's no reason I need to be using a dictionary... that's just an error on my end trying to look up solutions online lol. I'll play with it some more.

Comment: About the `'int' object is not subscriptable`, did you change the line to `count = {}` or `count = dict()`? If yes, then there would be some problem with the data you are providing...

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in data:
    if year_start <= item[0] <= year_end:
        # this year is in the range
```